# Tilemap 2D realistic fluid physics

Tags: c++, 2d, physics

I'm interested in trying to create realistic fluids (water), for a 2D game. This game is similar to Terraria. I have heard about how you can slap a bunch of colliding particles on the scene and render over it and voila, realistic acting water.

Terraria uses tile based water, which I am not a fan of.. I want something more advanced.

I thought about using bullet 3D physics (box2d has limits I would hit). For non colliding particle effects, I am thinking about using something like SPARK, since I think that'd give me the best of both worlds.

The issue I am thinking about, is that each block is 16x16, so on a 1600x900 scene, there are about 5 thousand tiles.

So I need to tell the physics engine that these tiles are collidable. Of course, there are void tiles that are considered to be non collidable.

Does anyone have ideas on this? Language is C++, I doubt that's relevant though.

EDIT: i think i'm going to have to cave in and use grid based water. I suppose, in retrospect particle based just makes everything more difficult but for what gain?

Answer (score 3):

Your question is about tiled fluids, but you seem to actually be asking about a particle based approach.

If that's the case, what you're looking for is "Smoothed Particle Hydrodynamics", or SPH, which is a very popular technique for 2D and 3D fluid simulations in realtime situations.

Yes, it's basically just a particle system, with each particle responding to the forces in your environment (gravity, collisions etc.) in a reasonable (mathematically stable) way, combined with a constraint that they must stay a certain distance apart in order that the fluid is incompressible.

You can render the particles as points, if you have enough of them, or you can use them as a source for deriving a surface (for example using marching-cubes, though in 2D I wouldn't worry about that).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoothed-particle_hydrodynamics

It has the advantage of being relatively easy to code, and indeed to accelerate on a GPU.

Indeed I think they're probably a better approach than trying some kind of tile-based approach, and you get some more interesting results, such as spray kicking up, waves kicking against the edges of objects, etc. It's not too hard to get something pleasing working, I'd give it a go.

Comment: Hmm..I guess you're making me redecide with this, hehe. Could you elaborate though? You didn't give me ideas of how to make the particles collide against the tilemap. Additionally, what kind of libraries would have this? There's no way I'd be able to implement this math myself, especially when other people could do better.

Comment: Also, what alternatives to SPH are there? Remember, this is a 2D game, not a particle simulator, so SPH does feel like overkill...

Comment: It's probably one of the simplest approaches if you want realistic fluids. If you think that's overkill, there probably aren't many options that are really fluid-like.